# Using a own Model to be the User login

Tags: python, django, model

I have a doubt about authentification with my own Model. In my project I have a Pacient Model and I need that to be saved on the Users panel in the Admin site.

Basically I recover the data from a HTML form (they're generated in a  , it was a request for the test)

(Do not worry about the validations)

```
models.py

class Pacient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    birthday = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField()
    confirmPass = models.CharField()
```

In the forms.py file

```
class PacientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField
    birthday = forms.DateField
    email = forms.EmailField
    password = forms.CharField
    confirmPass = forms.CharField


class Meta:
    model = Pacient
    fields =('name','birthday','email','password','confirmPass')
```

Using those fields I can save data in the table Pacient. It can be seen in the admin site but separated from the Groups and Users under the project name.

So, my question is this. How can I made the Pacient Model to be recognized as the User (in the admin site) and login using the "email" as the username?

Comment: Do you mean "patient"?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `AbstractBaseUser` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
```

This Base model can be inherited by your `Pacient` model, then in settings.py file you can set:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.Pacient'
```

This will tell django to use your model for auth purposes.

More infos here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'll test it right now. I'l be back if something happens.